# How do you add graphics to a dylib?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia

I just started learning how to write mobile substrate addons, and have successfully been able to create a dylib that hooks into a native iphone app. My question is, how do I go about adding images to my dylib file so they can be displayed in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, use a Bundle for Images, Localization Files and XIBs

For more info in bundles check out [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i) by Apple.

Comment: Thats what i figured.  Since all i have is a dylib file (no app) can you point me to somewhere that will help me out with being able to add a bundle and access it from my code.

Comment: Added a link to the Bundle Programming Guide